# Image boundary based on superpixels

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation, boundary, superpixels

Superpixels that located in the image boundary can be specified manually using appropriate index (such as the following example for the second superpixel, `L==2`):

[image: Segmented Image]

[image: Selected superpixel]

In some cases it is needed to specify all of those superpixels located in the image boundary in an systematic and non-manual way, something similar to the image below:

[image: superpixel image without edge superpixels]

Is there any standard method to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the labeled image `L`,

```
lr = L([1,end],:);
```

are all pixels along the left and right edges, and

```
tb = L(:,[1,end]);
```

are all pixels along the top and bottom edges. We can find all labels that touch the image edge by taking the unique values in those to sets:

```
labels = unique([lr(:);tb(:));
```